MS Graph API list of all events that were forwarded to me
I'm trying to write a query in the Graph API that shows me all calendar events that have been forwarded to me.
In other words, events to which I was not directly invited.
A list with all events is not a problem, but is there a way to limit it like this?
Perhaps a ‘SingleValueExtendedProperty’

You could give PidLidForwardInstance a try https://learn.microsoft.com/sk-sk/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidlidforwardinstance-canonical-property but I don't think its actual used
